# How to make the checking more robust and shorter?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, big-o

**I wrote this code, but I dont uderstand why it works this way, especially using the third and fourth examples as input. Why the 'middle' position remains so behind? -in the number 5 (or index 2) using the [1, 3, 5, 6] array and the number 7 as target??**

**And how to make it better??**
I cant think of a shorter or better way to check the if/elses **when the target value is not in the array, especially if the input is an array with only one value and the target to find is 0.**
Maybe a better way to check the possible different scenarios.
Or how to better check the correct place of the target without so many if/elses.

For example, is this code good enough to a coding interview? What can I do better?

from LeetCode:

> **Search Insert Position**

> **Given a sorted array of distinct integers and a target value, return the index if the target is found. If not, return the index where it would be if it were inserted in order.**

> You must write an algorithm with O(log n) runtime complexity.

Example 1:
Input: nums = [1,3,5,6], target = 5
Output: 2

Example 2:
Input: nums = [1,3,5,6], target = 2
Output: 1

**Example 3:
Input: nums = [1,3,5,6], target = 7
Output: 4**

**And especially this one:
Example 4:
Input: nums=[1], target= 0**

Constraints:
1 <= nums.length <= 104
-104 <= nums[i] <= 104
nums contains distinct values sorted in ascending order.
-104 <= target <= 104

---

**this is my code:**

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} target
 * @return {number}
 */
var searchInsert = function(nums, target) {
    let left = 0;
    let right = nums.length -1;
    let middle;
    while(left <= right){
        middle = nums.length>1 ? (Math.floor(left + (right - left)/2)) : 0;
        if(nums[middle] === target){
            return middle;
        } else if(target < nums[middle]){
            right = middle -1;
        } else {
            left = middle + 1;
        }
    }
    
    console.log(`Middle: ${middle}`);
    console.log(`Middle-1: ${nums[middle-1]}`);
    if(nums.lenght === 1){
        return 0;
    } else {
        if((target < nums[middle] && target > nums[middle-1] )|| (target < nums[middle] && nums[middle-1] === undefined)){ /*
No more items to the left ! */
        return middle; 
    } else if(target<nums[middle] && target<nums[middle-1]){
        return middle-1;
    } else if(target > nums[middle] && target > nums[middle + 1]) {
        return middle + 2; /* Why the 'middle' is so behind here? using the THIRD example as input?? */
    } else {
        return middle + 1;
    }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

The issue lies in the variable you are checking for after the `while` loop.

In a "classical" binary search algorithm, reaching beyond the `while` loop would indicate the `needle` isn't present in the `haystack`. In case of this problem, though, we simply need to return `right + 1` in this place in the code (rather than checking the `middle`).

Your code adjusted for this:

```js
var searchInsert = function(nums, target) {
    let left = 0;
    let right = nums.length -1;
    let middle;
    while(left <= right){
        middle = nums.length>1 ? (Math.floor(left + (right - left)/2)) : 0;
        if(nums[middle] === target){
            return middle;
        } else if(target < nums[middle]){
            right = middle -1;
        } else {
            left = middle + 1;
        }
    }
    
    return right + 1;
};

console.log(
  searchInsert([1,3,5,6], 5),
  searchInsert([1,3,5,6], 2),
  searchInsert([1,3,5,6], 7),
  searchInsert([1], 0)
);
```

---

### Side note

Also, the below is redundant...

```js
middle = nums.length>1 ? (Math.floor(left + (right - left)/2)) : 0;
```

...and can be shortened to:

```js
middle = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
```

---

## Revised variant

```js
const searchInsertProblem = (arr, n) => {
    let start = 0;
    let end   = arr.length - 1;
 
    while (start <= end) {
        const middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        
        if (arr[middle] === n) { return  middle; }     // on target
        if (arr[middle] > n)   { end   = middle - 1; } // overshoot
        else                   { start = middle + 1; } // undershoot
    }
 
    return end + 1;
};

console.log(
  searchInsertProblem([1,3,5,6], 5),
  searchInsertProblem([1,3,5,6], 2),
  searchInsertProblem([1,3,5,6], 7),
  searchInsertProblem([1], 0)
);
```